# What is a 40 gross tonnage boat like?

Tags: boats

I am about to start a course for boating license for boats up to 40 gross tons. I wonder how big such a boat is?

I looked everywhere for concrete examples, but most only provide length or other metrics.

Is such a boat huge? Is it like a motor boat in tourist areas for 4-5 people?

Comment: https://www.delawarebusinessincorporators.com/pages/vessel-gross-tonnage-calculator

Comment: Imagine a [40-ton container](https://www.mwmwarbirds.co.uk/shop/tamiya-40-foot-container-semi-trailer-for-tamiya-1-14-r-c-tractor-truck-item-no-56326-0000/) on a semi trailer. Compare that with a [motor boat](https://www.boatsandoutboards.co.uk/boat/2012-beneteau-antares-7.80-8420486/) for 5 people.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, that makes sense! So its fairly large. Maybe even up to 10 people depending on boat?

Comment: @user1721135 Are you sure the boating license says "gross tonage"? That is a very strange measure for pleasure boats, as they're normally not measured according to that.

Comment: I imagine most _concrete_ vessels are substantially in excess of 40 tons... ;)

Comment: @TobySpeight Sounds funny, but there _have actually been_ vessels constructed from concrete. Note that gross tonnage is not equivalent to weight/displacement.

Comment: @PMF, yes - I assumed that was understood.  I was observing that they tend to be much bigger than your typical recreational yacht.  In fact, I happen to live quite near to where the Ninian Central oil storage platform was built - 600,000 tonnes of concrete, and the world's largest movable object at the time.

Comment: A lot of houseboats to be used in canals are based on concrete hulls. Not very useful for sailing but not much bigger than the sizes I use in my answer.

Comment: @user1721135 "Maybe even up to 10 people depending on boat":  Carrying up to 10 people could depend on the type of license--In the US, there is a license for up to 6 passengers, and a different license for 7 or more:  https://wow.uscgaux.info/content.php?unit=054-09&category=captains-license-info and https://www.dco.uscg.mil/nmc/charter_boat_captain/

Comment: @DaveX my license is Bulgarian internationally recognized not sure if it has a person limit as far as I know it doesn’t only boat size.

Comment: @PMF yes absolutely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A boat of 40 gross registered tonnes is a substantial vessel.**

For example [here is a link to a vessel for sale of 48 GRT.](https://www.boatdealers.ca/boats-for-sale/168266/giliken-mahogany-passenger-boat-built-by-james-giliken-other-new-york) It's a "passenger carrying boat used in tourist areas" like the ones you are asking about. This one is sixty foot long and carries 95 passengers.

Comment: Passengers vessels may be rather flat bottomed and having an angular cross section, with very little space for anything but passenger seats. Yachts stick quite often much deeper, with space for bed(s) and more space per seat, as well as space which is not useful or used for storage of water and such.  If the license only gives gross tonnage as limit you have to compare with the boat you expect to use, not with a different kind of vessel.

Comment: The OP asks about passenger-carrying tourist boats.

Comment: A motor boat for 4 - 5 people sounds like a yacht to me, not like a many people capable tourist boat.

Comment: "Yacht" can mean a lot of different things, from small sailboat to giant luxury cruiser.

Comment: Thanks Anton or even 40! Now I feel more motivated about the 100h of theory awaiting me.

Comment: @user1721135 What country are you in? 100h of theory is a lot of work, and if you are just looking to drive a pleasure boat there may be an easier license to get.

Comment: @DJClayworth Bulgaria. This is the standard / lowest boating license. However you can also drive without license if your boat is below 25kw. But if you get the license you have no limits apart from the tonnage, you can go anywhere basically. Its a lot but I feel that it will be worth it. Don't want to kill my self at sea. At least I can do the theory remotely since covid, which is comfy.

Answer (score 1):

Having used google to get a feel, I found a [Wikipedia page about Gross tonnage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_tonnage) as well as several [tonnage calculators](https://calculator.academy/boat-gross-tonnage-calculator/#f1p1) which will help you work out to get the tonnage of a given boat.

I entered a few random sizes (as I am not a boat person the length may not be right for the width and depth, but these are which I used to get near 40,) length 40 feet, width 6 feet and depth 8 feet, and it came to 38.4 gross tonnage.
Find the sizes of a boat you would consider sailing and enter them, and see how they work out compared to the limit of 40.

I linked to the first calculator which did not insist on spam, no affiliation.

Comment: I don't know who came up with that calculator, but it's got some huge flaws. For example I have a sailboat with a displacement of around half a tonne, and a gross tonnage of not much more. If I enter the figures it tells me the tonnage is 3 tonnes. If I entered it's actual keel depth it tells me it's more than ten tonnes.

Comment: @DJClayworth, boats come in many different shapes and the calculator will likely only give good answers to one shape, yachts with a keel are likely not the basic they work on. I guess it will be more for freight boats, seeing your reaction.

Comment: I also fed in the figures for the example boat in my answer and it calculates the GRT to be more than twice what it really is.